# Getting 2 divs on the same line

Tags: asp.net, css, html

I'm trying to get 2 divs on the same line, I've got

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
     <div class="menuDiv">
             <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
                EnableViewState="False" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" BackColor="#E3EAEB"   DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" 
                Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#666666">
            </asp:Menu></div>

            <div class="SearchBox">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I wanna get the menu and the search inside the hideSkiplink with the menu to the left and the search to the right. As it is the search is under the menu. I tried changing  adding positions for everything on css as I found around this site,  but if I get the menu and search in the same line the hideSkiplink disappears, if I set the search to float right, it goes out of the hideSkiplink.

All I have in my css right now is

```
div.hideSkiplink
{
background-color:#555555;
width:100%;
 }

div.menu
{
padding: 8px 0px 8px 10px;   
}
```

any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#NavigationMenu {
    float: left;
}

.SearchBox {
    float: right;
}

.MenuDiv {
    overflow: hidden; /* adjusts the height of .MenuDiv to wrap its children */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set

`display: inline-block;`

And then set their widths as you need (as an absolute value or percentages of the parent container)

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb3U9/4/)

Comment: Thank you. Ended up using inline-block with the post above so I didn't need to include any widths or heights.

Answer (score 0):

Add float : left; attribute to the div.menu

Answer (score 0):

You can play with float:

```
float: left;
float: right;
clear: both;
```

This is not always easy to do.

Another option is to use

```
display: inline-block;
```

or to use a span.

Answer (score 0):

line-height(child-elements) with a combination of the previous answers