# How to insert divs on the same line

Tags: html, css, position, block, margin

I'm trying to insert 4 divs on the same line, but they go each after each. I was working on but I couldn't find the problem. I can place blocks in the good place by moving it with margin function, but I think there is a better way.

It looks at the moment:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWkET.png)

```
#recent_work {
    width:952px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:15px;

}

#recent_work p:first-child {
    font-family:Montserrat;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#353c3e;
    width:238px;
}

#recent_work p:nth-child(2) {
    font-family:Montserrat;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#8f8f8f;
    width:190px;
    line-height:25px;
}

.grey_block {
    float:right;
    background-color:#eaeaea;
    width:230px;
    height:489px;

}

.orange_block {
    width:230px;
    height:205px;
    background-color:#e05d41;
}

.white_block {
    width:230px;
    height:281px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}



<div id="recent_work">
            <p>RECENT WORK</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis laoreet laoreet leo at dictum.</p>
            <div class="grey_block">
                <div class="orange_block">
                    <img src="img/1.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="white_block">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting 2 divs on the same line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166167/getting-2-divs-on-the-same-line), among many [others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=divs+on+the+same+line)

Comment: Instead of `div` you can use `span` which is not adding the new-line. Please create a Fiddle demo for it, http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

You should either make the divs `display: inline-block` or `float: left` depending on the actual results you want to achieve in the end.

Answer (score 0):

In your style `p` element taking the full width that why image is coming just below.

since parent div have already `relative position` so you can set `absolute position` to child div.

```
.grey_block {
  position:absolute; /*Added line*/
  top:0; /*star from top*/
  right:0; /*Start from right*/
  background-color:#eaeaea;
  width:230px;
  height:489px;
}
```

Check the **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/boluzeri/1)**.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
position:relative top:somepx left:somepx;
```

this will help u to achieve the goal of u..just give somepx to top or left..