# two divs on the same line within a parent on the same line

Tags: html, css

So, I did a search and it seems that every single person who's asked this exact same question has actually had success with an answer given by someone - I tried multiple different methods and honestly, I'm about to have a meltdown.

I've tried floating left, floating right, inline-block, etc, and *none* of it has seemed to work. I am at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong, but it's driving me nuts.

Here's the HTML I'm trying to get on the same line:

```
<div class="search-and-staff-app-button">
   <div class="search-position">
     <form method="get" id="sb_searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/">
       <div class='search-box'>
         <input name="s" id="s" class='search-input' placeholder='Search' type='text' />
         <img onclick="document.getElementById('sb_searchform').submit();" class='search-img' src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/search.png'>
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>

   <div id="staffAppButtonPlaceholder" class="staff-app-position"></div>

</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.search-and-staff-app-button {
    width:360px;
    margin:0px;
    float:right;
    display: inline-block;
}

.search-position {
    float:left;
}

.staff-app-position {
    float:left;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried [Getting 2 divs on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166167/getting-2-divs-on-the-same-line) and this doesn't work either.

Any help would be super appreciated!

-Stu

Comment: Please link to a jsfiddle

Comment: Please use jsfiddle, and explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve. Seems like you are missing content in the #staffAppButtonPlaceholder div.

Comment: which of the divs? there are 4 of them

Comment: Your code is a bit all over the place. Can you illustrate what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place the `search-position` and `staffAppButtonPlaceholder` divs on the same line, first float the search-position div:

```
.search-position {
    float: left;
}
```

Then add some content to the placeholder:

```
<div id="staffAppButtonPlaceholder" class="staff-app-position">Content</div>
```

Finally, increase the width of the containing div to allow the elements to fit side-by-side:

```
.search-and-staff-app-button {
    width:760px;
```

Both divs will now be aligned horizontally.

http://jsfiddle.net/jzefu2j9/1/

Comment: While this does seem to work, they are extremely far apart on my page (I can't post a photo because I don't have enough reputation). To clarify, the placeholder div literally calls on a dropdown button, so the div just needs to be present.

Another part of the issue is that it pushes down the navbar so the labels for the nav can't be seen :S

Comment: figured it out! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little example, maybe it will help you. I used flexbox, which in my opinion is a great solution for aligning.

```
.search-and-staff-app-button{
  display: flex;
  background:red;
  align-items:center;
}
.search-and-staff-app-button > div{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:block;
  flex:1 50%;
  align-self:center;
  padding:1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pulamc/u9nLwacs/

Answer (score -1):

add style="position:relative" to your outer div. Then make the inner div's style="position:absolute;left:0". You will have to manually set the left value for each of the divs. The downside is that you will have to know the width of the other divs on the same line.